# How to log the values that cause a unique constraint violation

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I have a lengthy `INSERT` statement running on Oracle that fails with:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYPROJECT.MYTABLE_PK) violated
```

The constraint is:

```
CONSTRAINT "MYTABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENCOUNTER_NUM", "CONCEPT_CD", "PROVIDER_ID", "START_DATE", "MODIFIER_CD")
```

The problematic `INSERT` statement is logged, but not the values causing the constraint violation.

Is there a way to log or otherwise save and view the values that violated the constraint?

This is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Could you please add the version of Oracle that you're using to your question? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DML error logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2)

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log( dml_table_name => 'MYTABLE' );
end;
/

insert into mytable
  <<your select statement>>
  log errors into err$mytable
  reject limit unlimited;
```

This will log all the rows that violated a constraint to the `err$mytable` table.

Comment: Or you could drop the constraint - insert all the data and then do a SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE "ENCOUNTER_NUM" = "ENCOUNTER_NUM" AND "CONCEPT_CD" = "CONCEPT_CD".... &c) - that should give you a list of offending records. BTW, why are you using double-quotes - they'll only mess with your SQL (make it case-sensitive) and make it difficult to port your app should you choose another RDBMS. BTW, I prefer @Justin Cave's solution - much more elegant.

Comment: Many thanks. And thanks also for the tip on double quotes. I'm a neophyte Oracle user cautiously poking around in legacy code to make it a little less fragile so I will change the quotes.